# Android and Paypal API integration

Tags: android, integration, paypal

I'm trying to integrate the `Paypal API` to make my app donation based. I have two questions:

1. I can see the button, I click it but it doesn't do anything! (the activity for checkoutIntent doesn't fire?)
2. What are your experiences with donation based android apps? I want to make about $250 a month of this thing, is that even possible?

```
public class Donate extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

     PayPal ppObj = PayPal.initWithAppID(this.getBaseContext(), "APP-80W284485P519543T", PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.donate);
      LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);
      if (ppObj == null) ppObj = PayPal.initWithAppID(this.getBaseContext(), "APP-80W284485P519543T", PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);
      CheckoutButton payPalButton = (CheckoutButton) ppObj.getPaymentButton(PayPal.BUTTON_294x45, this, PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_HARD_GOODS);
      payPalButton.setOnClickListener(this);
      mainLayout.addView(payPalButton);
     }

     public void onClick(View arg0) {
      PayPalPayment newPayment = new PayPalPayment();
      newPayment.setAmount((float) 1.00);
      newPayment.setCurrency("USD");
      newPayment.setRecipient("example@example.com");
      Intent checkoutIntent = new Intent(this, PayPalActivity.class);
      checkoutIntent.putExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT_INFO, newPayment);

      this.startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, 1);
     }

     @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
      Intent menuIntent = new Intent(Donate.this, MTGTools.class);
         this.startActivity(menuIntent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with what you are doing.  Are you sure that the launchPayPalButton you have in oncreate is the same one as you are clicking?  Re #2..that entirely depends on how good your app is..

Comment: It wasn't. I figured out that I had to add that paypal button to my layout. I'm going to edit my code to reflect my changes. 

2. It's a magic: the gathering health tracker application, there are a bunch of free ones on the market, but I'm going to be building card recognition into mine. (Hopefully)

Comment: Also, can I even make a sandbox call to paypal from my emulator?

Comment: It's very unlikely you'll make $250/mo from donations

Comment: hi are you able to get the thing run under live mode... if so.... how... can you please let me...

Answer (score 0):

In `onclick`:

```
pp=PayPal.getInstance();

// Should do like this to start paypal activity
PayPalPayment newPayment = new PayPalPayment();
newPayment.setCurrencyType("USD");

Intent paypalIntent=pp.checkout(newPayment, test.this);
startActivityForResult(paypalIntent, 1);
```